# GCC: Inconsistent "undefined function" warnings?

Tags: gcc

Recently I've been poking around and trying to figure out how C compilers work.

I've noticed that different computers seem to exhibit different behaviours for the following actions:

```
// a.c

// #include"oui.h"
int main() {
  oui();
}
```

```
// oui.h

void oui();
```

`gcc -c a.c`

On one computer, I am warned that function `oui` in `a.c` is undefined. This makes sense to me, and uncommenting the include fixes the problem.

On another computer, however, even with the include commented out, the compiler produces the object `a.o` without complaint. This does *not* make sense to me, because isn't `oui` undefined without the header file?

Which is the normal behaviour? Are some settings on one of my computers messed up?

*Don't bother with the following questions if you don't want to, they just popped into my mind and I'll make another thread if need be :).*

Side question: The `-c` flag produces object files but does not link, so is there a special "link" flag afterwards to put the object files together, or is it just `gcc`? Why not just gcc everything together at the start?

Side question #2: if I do `gcc filea fileb filec`, is `filea` inherently special for being the first argument? Or does the order of gcc not matter because the compiler finds whichever file has `main` by itself?

Comment: What are the exact error messages or warnings?  An error about `oui` being **undefined** would be strange.  An error about it being **undeclared** or **implicitly declared** is what I would expect.

Comment: The distinction between **definition** and **declaration** is critical here.  You might like to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's maybe a version difference between the two computers.

Which is the normal behaviour?
The compiler should warn, if you use a function, that isn't declared.

Are some settings on one of my computers messed up?
I don't think so, that you have one newer gcc and a older one.

Side question #1:
If you use gcc without `-c`, it will try to invoke the linker. In this example, the linker will fail, as `oui` is undefined.
`-c` is often used in Makefiles/for bigger projects, as you can recompile faster, because the compiler doesn't have to compile every source file again.

Side question #2:
The order of the source files doesn't matter, as the linker finds `main` by itself.